# Nginx doen't work with location, just ports

Tags: nginx, ssl, server, port, ubuntu-server

I'm trying to configure a server with some shiny apps. I've changed my internet connection and I had to configure a ddns with no-ip. So far so good. Now I'm configuring the Nginx file, which used to work perfectly before, but now I can't get into the correct url without writting the port. For example, you can check the real app here:

http://shiny-server.modlearth.com:3838/windfarm-viewsheds/

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    listen 81;
    listen [::]:81 ipv6only=on;
    #port_in_redirect off;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 444 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:444 ssl http2 default_server;

    server_name _;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    # index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.modlearth.com;
    }

    location /shiny/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3838/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        #rewrite ^(/shiny/[^/]+)$ $1/ permanent;
    }
```

As the providers told me that the restrict the ports 80 and 443 for them. I changed them to 81 and 444 to get it work with secure connection. So I have now two problems:

1. I can't get to the url without writting the port (not online neither locally)
2. Even with the port written, the connection doesn't seem to use ssl ans secure connection now. If you remove the port in the url it looks like there is something blocking it. The ports are open in the router too.

Update:
Here is my current ports config:
[image]

Also, in the router part, I have the ports open for the actual internal ip of the server.